# Multiprocessing crash with basic tkinter interface with Python 3.4.3 in OS X

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, multiprocessing

I'm trying to run tkinter frames as separate processes, but when I do so using a relatively basic script the process either finishes without starting any windows, or crashes.

```
from tkinter import *
from multiprocessing import Process

titles = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']

class Demo(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, fname="", **options):
        Frame.__init__(self, master=parent, **options)
        self.pack()
        Label(self, text=fname).pack(side=TOP)
        Button(self, text="Quit!", command=self.quit).pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)

def runDemo(name):
    Demo(fname=name).mainloop() #call and run class instance...

if __name__=="__main__":
    for name in titles:
        #runDemo(name)
        Process(target=runDemo, args=(name,)).start() #spawn process...
```

This at least runs if I uncomment the "runDemo(name)" line and comment out the Process call; however, this has the window instances spawn in sequence in the same process, and not in separate processes as desired.

As far as I can tell, everything in this code ought to run the separate processes as expected.

This is using Python 3.4.3 on OS X 10.10.4. I am primarily developing in PyCharm Community Edition 4.5, but this happens when run either in PyCharm or directly from the command line. Any clues?

Updated to add crash logs:

```
Process:               Python [24917]
Path:                  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            Python
Version:               3.4.3 (3.4.3)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        Python [24916]
Responsible:           pycharm [20749]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2015-07-05 17:55:24.271 -0700
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.4 (14E46)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        02AA8592-98B0-87D9-7BA0-938C3E157C6B

Sleep/Wake UUID:       DABF4CDD-2502-4E5C-84EB-74CD9BBD6C33

Time Awake Since Boot: 180000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       8700 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000110

VM Regions Near 0x110:
--> 
__TEXT                 0000000100000000-0000000100001000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

Application Specific Information:
*** multi-threaded process forked ***
crashed on child side of fork pre-exec
```

Comment: Does it throw any `Traceback` error message ?, because I've tried on Windows 7 with Python 2.7 and it runs without any issue. I got the four Frames...

Comment: I have no issues running it on Ubuntu 15.04. Can you please post the exception message?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the post to include part of the crash log. The meat of it appears to be with the "crashed on child side of fork pre-exec" statement. I'm not sure what I can do about this. Since it appears to work on other platforms, could this be a bug in the latest python version for OS X?

Comment: Try adding `multiprocessing .set_start_method('forkserver')` https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, That was it! Yeah, upon further investigation it is some bug in how tkinter works in OS X, and this makes it work. Thanks for the find.

Comment: my multiprocessing application run just fine on python 3.4 and 2.7 under osX 10.7, but under osX 10.10 with python 2.7 i get the same error as here. using the python 2.7 that ships with osX 10.10, i get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_start_method'` on the multiprocessing module